# Typescript v2.2.2 union type makes error (TS2339)

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

In my angular 2 I use ngrx and have some actions and reducers. Example of actions :

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

export const actionTypes = {
  ACTION_1: type('Actions 1'),
  ACTION_2: type('Actions 2'),
};

export class ActionOne implements Action {
  public type = actionTypes.ACTION_1;

  constructor(public payload: any) { }
}

export class ActionTwo implements Action {
  public type = actionTypes.ACTION_2;
}

export type Actions
  = ActionOne
  | ActionTwo;
```

So, some actions has payload, others - no, and `Actions` is union type, which can be `ActionOne` or `ActionTwo`. But in me reducer I have an error: `Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'Actions' Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'ActionTwo'.`

Reducer is like this:

```
export function reducer(state = initialState, action: Actions): IState {
  switch (action.type) {

    case actions.actionTypes.ACTION_1: {
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        data: action.payload,
      });
    }

    case ...
  }
}
```

I got this error after updating typescript version from `2.0.3` to `2.2.2`.
So, is there way to fix error without putting payload to every action? May be is there some option from `tsconfog.json` for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare the constants in a namespace, instead of a dictionary. This allows ACTION_1 and ACTION_2 take the literal type, which is essential for discrimated union to work.

```
export namespace actionTypes {
    export const ACTION_1 = 'Action 1';  // <-- type of ACTION_1 is 'Action 1' in TS 2.1+
    export const ACTION_2 = 'Action 2';
};
```

The `type` of each `class` needs to be a constant, otherwise the type of `type` would be `string` instead of literal type.

```
export class ActionOne implements Action {
    public readonly type = actionTypes.ACTION_1;   // <-- note the `readonly`
    constructor(public payload: any) { }
}

export class ActionTwo implements Action {
    public readonly type = actionTypes.ACTION_2;
}
```

---

The `ACTION_ONE: type('Action one')` pattern has been deprecated by ngrx developers since TypeScript 2.1 / Angular 4. See https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/pull/88#issuecomment-272623083 for information.

Comment: `type()` is not from typescript, it's util function for ngrx

Answer (score -1):

You know inside this switch case which action it is so you can cast to the appropriate one:

```
case actions.actionTypes.ACTION_1: {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
        data: (action as ActionOne).payload,
    });
}
```

The compiler is obviously right as the union results in a type that has only the shared properties, and `payload` isn't one of them.

Comment: I wonder why people don't like the answer.  It does solve the problem and rather easily.